# How can I place buttons over an image and adjust content for different devices in .net maui

Tags: visual-studio, maui

I want to create an UI in .net Maui with an image and buttons over specific locations of that, like above.[image]

Each circle is a button that shows in label "local do toque" the region of the body, like shoulder, elbow, etc.

Part of the code I'm using in xaml is as follow

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
   <Image x:Name="corlett" Source="corlett2.png" Aspect="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="0.9" Margin="-20,20,0,0"></Image>
           
   <Grid>
       <Button x:Name="OmbroDAnt" CornerRadius="25" BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Green" 
               BorderWidth="1" Margin="38,100,10,10" Scale="0.6"></Button>
   </Grid>
   <Grid>
       <Button x:Name="OmbroEAnt" CornerRadius="25" BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Green" 
               BorderWidth="1" Margin="118,100,10,10" Scale="0.6"></Button>
   </Grid>

   <Grid>
       <Button x:Name="ClaviculaDAnt" CornerRadius="25" BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Green" 
               BorderWidth="1" Margin="64,98,10,10" Scale="0.5"></Button>
   </Grid>
   <Grid>
       <Button x:Name="ClaviculaEAnt" CornerRadius="25" BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Green" 
               BorderWidth="1" Margin="91,98,10,10" Scale="0.5"></Button>
   </Grid>
   ------


    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="locationLabel" Text="Local do toque:" Margin="150,500"/>
    </Grid>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

However the position of items changes according to devices. I've tried FlexLayout, VestricalStackLayout but none of them allows m to place buttons over image, only AbsoluteLayout. How can I fix this? Many thanks!

Comment: If the image size and ratio are fixed, it can be done with Grid + BoxView (or Border) with TapGesture attached and transparent background color. Position the BoxViews with proper margins.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `AbsoluteLayout` but you have to indicate the position/size of the element being proportional to its parent. For that you need to use [AbsoluteLayoutFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.layouts.absolutelayoutflags?view=net-maui-7.0) which will indicate how the values you provide are taken.

In your specific case, I'd first of all not use margins at all inside the absolute layout, if you need to specify margins to correctly position the Image do it on the layout instead of inside. Then the Image should cover all the space of the layout to have easier proportions, otherwise you need to calculate any scale/translation you may apply to the image.

Then e.g. you can check that the left circle on the shoulder is let's say at 1/5th of the width from the left and 1/6th of the height from the top, then you can set the value of that like the following:

```xml
<AbsoluteLayout 
   ...>
   
   ...
        
    <Button 
        x:Name="OmbroDAnt" 
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.20, 0.17, 0.02, 0.02"
        CornerRadius="25" 
        BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
        BorderColor="Green"
        BorderWidth="1"  />

   ...
```

So `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"` will indicate that you'll use proportional position and sizing and `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds` the values for each of them: x, y, width, height. You can find more info [here (AbsoluteLayout class)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.absolutelayout?view=net-maui-7.0) and [here (Layouts -> AbsoluteLayout)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/#absolutelayout)

For the image, if not scale/translation is added you'd have:

```xml
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
```

Maybe you'd need to calculate and set the size of the `AbsoluteLayout` based on the size of the device's screen and the ratio of the image so everything fits as it supposed to and the image is shown with the same size ratio on each device thus it maintains its proportions.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Contrary to the documentation, I have found that in proportional mode that the meaning of `x, y` in `x, y, width, height` changes from the upper-left corner to the center. So, the placement of the image actually is `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 1, 1"`. However, during testing, you won't notice because there is a clamping imposed so that the child never goes out of bounds from the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `TapGestureRecognizer` directly on the `Image` and use `GetPosition` to resolve the `(x, y)` coordinates relative to the image:

```xml
<Image x:Name="corlett" Source="corlett2.png">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

```cs
void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TappedEventArgs e)
{
    // Position relative to an Image
    Point? relativeToImagePosition = e.GetPosition((View) sender);

    // lookup body part based on relative position
    // ...
}
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/tap?view=net-maui-7.0

An interesting algorithm exists with a secondary hidden image where each click location has a unique color. With that in place, we can use this image to rapidly identify any point being clicked by the user by resolving the pixel color of the click location:

[image: colored-parts]

One method of implementing this requires the use of the 3rd party SkiaSharp package and that you place your image where SkiaSharp can load. For this example, I place it in `Resources/Raw/rawidentify2.png` and then I can load the `rawidentify2.png` into a `SKBitmap` so that it can later be used for identification during the gesture recognizer:

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    SkiaSharp.SKBitmap identifyBitmap = null;
    IDictionary<Color, string> color_to_bodypart = new Dictionary<Color, string>()
    {
        {  Color.FromArgb("#ed1c24"), "Left Shoulder" },
        {  Color.FromArgb("#00a2e8"), "Left Clavical" },
        {  Color.FromArgb("#22b14c"), "Right Clavical" },
        {  Color.FromArgb("#ff7f27"), "Right Shoulder" },
        // ...
    };

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Task.Run( async () =>
        {
            Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("rawidentify2.png");
            if (stream != null)
            { 
                identifyBitmap = SkiaSharp.SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
            }
        } );
    }

    void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Position relative to a View
        View view = (View)sender;
        Point? viewPos = e.GetPosition(view);
        // Debug.WriteLine($"viewPos = {viewPos}");

        // Position relative to internal image.
        double s = Math.Max((double)identifyBitmap.Width / view.Width,
                            (double)identifyBitmap.Height / view.Height);
        int imageX = (int)(viewPos.Value.X * s);
        int imageY = (int)(viewPos.Value.Y * s);
        // Debug.WriteLine($"imagePos = {imageX} {imageY}");

        // lookup body part based on relative position
        if (imageX >= 0 && imageX < identifyBitmap.Width && imageY >= 0 && imageY <= identifyBitmap.Height)
        {
            SkiaSharp.SKColor c = identifyBitmap.GetPixel(imageX, imageY);
            Color c2 = new Color(c.Red, c.Green, c.Blue, c.Alpha);
            // Debug.WriteLine($"identify color = {c} {c2}");
            if (color_to_bodypart.ContainsKey(c2))
            {
                var bodypart = color_to_bodypart[c2];
                Debug.WriteLine($"identify bodypart = {bodypart}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```